Maintaining SendKeys Functionality for an External Form in C# Application
I'm encountering an issue with sending keys from an external form in my C# application. Here's the scenario:
In my application, I have two forms - let's call them FormA and ALP_KEYBOARD. In FormA, there's a button triggering a method BtnSearchItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e), which in turn calls the ALP_KEYBOARD form.
Approach 1 (Problematic):
private void BtnSearchItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Application.Run(new ALP_KEYBOARD());
    });
}

When using this approach to call the ALP_KEYBOARD form, the keyboard functionality works as expected, sending keys to any focused input within the application. However, this method doesn't retain the association with the calling form.
But, if I close ALP_KEYBOARD that is opened and reclick on BtnSearchItem_Click, then ALP_KEYBOARD's topmost and top-level functionality never works again, except after closing ALP_KEYBOARD and waiting about 40 to 50 seconds before reclicking BtnSearchItem_Click. Only then does ALP_KEYBOARD work as expected.
Approach 2 (Limited Functionality):
private void BtnSearchItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ALP_KEYBOARD aLP_KEYBOARD = new ALP_KEYBOARD();
    aLP_KEYBOARD.Show(); /*OR*/ aLP_KEYBOARD.ShowDialog();
}

Using this approach, where the ALP_KEYBOARD form is directly shown, the form appears correctly, but it fails to send keys to the form that invoked it or any other form within the application.
What I'm aiming for is to have the ALP_KEYBOARD form retain the ability to send keys to the originating form (FormA) or any other form within the application while also being properly displayed.
Here's the constructor and KeysFunction() method for ALP_KEYBOARD:
public ALP_KEYBOARD()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    KeysFunction();
}

private void KeysFunction()
{
    foreach (Control alpkeys in tableLayoutPanelAlphabets.Controls)
    {
        if (alpkeys is KryptonButton alphabetkey)
        {
            alphabetkey.Click += delegate
            {
                string textToSend = alphabetkey.Text;
                SendKeys.Send(textToSend);
                //this.Owner?.Focus();
            };
        }
    }
    foreach (Control numkeys in tableLayoutPanelNums.Controls)
    {
        if (numkeys is KryptonButton numberkey)
        {
            numberkey.Click += delegate
            {
                string textToSend = numberkey.Text;
                SendKeys.Send(textToSend);
                //this.Owner?.Focus();
            };
        }
    }
    foreach (Control symkeys in tableLayoutPanelSymbols.Controls)
    {
        if (symkeys is KryptonButton symbolkey)
        {
            symbolkey.Click += delegate
            {
                string textToSend = symbolkey.Text;
                SendKeys.Send(textToSend);
                //this.Owner?.Focus();
            };
        }
    }
}

How can I achieve this functionality where the ALP_KEYBOARD form maintains its SendKeys functionality while being correctly associated with the calling form or any other form within the application? Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
